# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \sinh\left(\frac{n + \sin(n!)}{n^2 + \sin^2(n!)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I’m trying to prove the convergence of this serie. I proved that it is not absolutely convergent, but it can converge since the $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n \sinh\left(\frac{n + \sin(n!)}{n^2 + \sin^2(n!)}\right)=0$$ I have tried to use also the Leibniz criterium, but I’m not able to prove that this is a decreasing sequence. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!